# Is correct to place a switch-block inside another one?

Tags: c#, web-services, optimization, switch-statement

I shall provide a piece of code from one method, where I'm trying to handle commands/values from the web-service.

```
 switch (cmdName)
 {
     case "getShapefile":

         switch (cmdValue)
         {
             case "buildings":
                 HandleShapeFile(ref shapfile);
                 break;
         }

     break;
 }
```

The idea is the next:

- I have several commands (about 7, e.g. get{X-Object})
- Also there are for about 10 values for each command, so the count of operations is: 70, and they are different.

How is better to handle values and develop a fine design of such an aim?

Comment: fore readability you should make a function that processes the values

Comment: Do you have a function for each of the 70 Operations? And if, do they have all the same signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could flatten the switch so you would have no need for multiple switch blocks.

```
switch(cmdName + "-" + cmdValue)
{
    case "getShapefile-buildings":
        HandleShapeFile(ref shapfile);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use methods for each of the 7.

```
 switch (cmdName)
 {
     case "getShapefile":
        HandleShapeFiles( cmdValue ); 
     break;
 }
```

and then have the second case statement in the method.

So the idea is, 7 methods, each with their own case statement of 10 options.